# Webpack report an error about Unexpected character '#'

Tags: webpack

I am using webpack to load dependencies. And one of the dependency is written like below:

```
#! /usr/bin/env node

'use strict'

var Parser = require('jsonparse')
  , through = require('through')
```

webpack gave me below error:

```
ERROR in ./~/JSONStream/index.js
Module parse failed: /Project/node_modules/JSONStream/index.js Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| #! /usr/bin/env node
```

It seems that the character `#` is not recognised by webpack. Is there a loader for me to use to load this kind of js file?

Comment: Make sure node binaries are in your environment path and remove the line `#! /usr/bin/env node` and see if it works.

Comment: remove that line works fine but it is a third party library I can't change its source code.

Comment: You can use the [shebang-loader](https://github.com/javascriptismagic/shebang-loader).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) `#!/usr/bin/env node` indicates that it's an executable script, which should not be a module at the same time. Library files and executables should be separated, since a CLI is just a way to use the library and if you're using the library yourself, you certainly don't want to have the CLI part included in your application.

Anyway, there is still a way around this. You can use the [`shebang-loader`](https://github.com/JavascriptIsMagic/shebang-loader) which has been mentioned in the [webpack issue #2168](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2168). Just add it to to your `.js` rule so the line gets removed.

Comment: Can you show example? having a lot of trouble getting this loader to work and the repo has no examples which is not helpful since the line (var command = require("shebang!../bin/command");) causes this error Error: Cannot find module 'shebang!../bin/command'.

Comment: this is the error im getting for trying to use the shebang-loader
ERROR in ./node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rc/index.js
Module parse failed: /Users/joseph/Documents/WebDevWorkspace/mvp_frontend/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rc/index.js Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| #! /usr/bin/env node
| var cc   = require('./lib/utils')
| var join = require('path').join
It is in a node_modules folder so I do not want to just go and erase the line, any help will be great, Thanks

Comment: @JMStudios.jrichardson Since webpack 2 you can't omit the `-loader` suffix, it resolves the loader literally. It would be `require("shebang-loader!./bin/command")` Or you can add it to your `.js` rule in your webpack config, e.g. `{ test: /\.js$/, use: ['babel-loader', 'shebang-loader'] }`.

Comment: Can't seem to make this work, any other solutions? My version should be "webpack@1.14.0"

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can choose to replace the shebang with an empty string by using the [`string-replace-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-replace-loader):

```
{
  test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
  loader: 'string-replace-loader',
  options: {
    search: '#!/usr/bin/env node',
    replace: '',
  }
}
```