# Error While Starting Angular Cli Server

Tags: angular, angular-cli-v6

I Just Generated my Application on WebStorm. When I run command `ng serve` this shows this error.

> ERROR in
>
> ./ansi-html  Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)  You
>   may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.  | #!/bin/sh 
>   | basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\,/,g')")  |   i ｢wdm｣: 
>   Failed to compile.

Comment: This can be of help - [Webpack report an error about Unexpected character '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403831/webpack-report-an-error-about-unexpected-character).

Comment: The Problem solved by just disabling the TSLint from WebStorm IDE setting.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Comment: I have switched to Ubuntu for using angular cli because I am not able to solve the problem. I think the problem was occurring with git. Try to uninstall git, node and npm and then try to configure angular I am not sure that will solve your problem or not but try it one time.