# When I try to create a project and run Angular 6, I get an error

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-cli-v6

I created a new project based on Angular documentation. I am using the latest version of Node and NPM.

- I am using NODE version 8.11.2
- I am using Node Package Manager version 6.4.1

I run this code:

```
D:\angular-examples\testing>ng serve

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

Date: 2018-09-09T11:27:36.200Z
Hash: 8e7632ec537c74fbb5ea
Time: 28220ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 11.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 227 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 15.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.26 MB [initial] [rendered]
```

But I get this error:

```
**ERROR in ./ansi-html 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
> #!/bin/sh
| basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
|
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.**
```

Comment: Looks like you’re trying to load a shell script into your bundle. Don’t know why.

Comment: What was the exact command you used to create the project?

Comment: Do you have `ansi-html` in your `package.json`? It seems this is not a default library for pure Angular project, created by CLI.

Comment: It seems you are not alone, a similar problem: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008349/error-while-starting-angular-cli-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51008349/error-while-starting-angular-cli-server)

Answer (score 1):

this is because `#` symbol is not recognized by `npm`. The `ng` command you are using to `serve` your project, is nothing more than a wrapper on `npm`. This issue is perhaps only limited to your version `6.4.1`, you can switch to the LTS version of `npm` which is `5.6.0`(included with node) or the version `6.4.0`. I have tested both on my machine (osx 10.9.5) and they both work.